# What does "But otherwise" mean

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've been reading HP and came across this para that I don't quite understand.

> “Well, you can’t blame him for wanting to get out and about,” said Ron, when Harry discussed
> his fears with him and Hermione. “I mean, he’s been on the run for over two years, hasn’t he,
> and I know that can’t have been a laugh, but at least he was free, wasn’t he? And now he’s just
> shut up all the time with that ghastly elf(Kreacher).”
> **Hermione scowled at Ron, but otherwise ignored the slight on Kreacher.**

I want to know what the highlighted part means.

My understanding is that Hermione got angry at Ron for insulting elf but then she ignored this and went on to talk about something else and not fight with Ron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Otherwise" can be understood as "other than that" or, in context "Other than scowling at Ron".

"A scowl" is, of course, a facial expression for anger. We learn in the second part that "Other than scowling, Hermione ignore the insult that Ron made about Kreacher"  In particular she didn't say anything to Ron (and this might be surprising since in the past she has been very talkative about Elf Welfare)

The fact that she mostly ignored Ron's comment contrasts with the fact that she did scowl.  So the two parts of the sentence are joined with "but".

So, yes she got angry, (but not very angry) and expressed this in her face, but chose not to say anything.